# Sound not working after installing ubuntu 12.04 LTS on compaq presario v3000 (32 bit)

Tags: 12.04, sound

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my old laptop, a Presario V3000, along with Windows Vista Basic.

Everything worked fine till I tried to play some music. No sound came! I checked sound settings in Bash. Everything was okay. Also, sound card drivers are not available for Linux on HP website. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Include `pci=realloc` kernel parameter in boot loader, It will fix sound, wireless and CPU overheating.

Comment: to whit, the following link explains how to go about doing this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters